# Why do values with quotes get read as blank after submitting the form?

Tags: html, string, forms, submit

should be a simple question to he who knows the answer...

```
<input type="hidden" name="english" value="\"oh no! i left my umbrella on the train\" \"you are a scatterbrain!\""/>                                                

<input type="hidden" name="english" value=""oh no! i left my umbrella on the train" "you are a scatterbrain!""/>
```

neither of these will properly submit the string in the form. how can i get strings with quotes to be submited?

Comment: Does `&quot;` work in an attribute?

Comment: Yes, but is it a php/asp/python/ruby/perl script right? Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace the quotes with the [HTML entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) `&quot;`. All programming languages related to the web have an easy way of doing this.

Alternatively you can place the value inside single quotes instead of double, which allows you to use double quotes without replacing them with entities -- but then of course you have to turn *single* quotes into entities instead.

Comment: In PHP it's the htmlentities function

Comment: @NoPyGod: Actually no, it's `htmlspecialchars`. `htmlentities` does more than it needs to, and most of the time that ends up being not what you wanted.

Comment: That's why I've asked what was expecting on the other side

Comment: dang, i was replacing with &amp;quot and wondering why it wasn't working. i forgot one stupid ";" at the end. thanks anyways.